# Too many views despite reusing layouts

Tags: android, xml, android-layout, android-studio, android-view

I'm trying to lower the view count within my layout to <=80 to get rid of the 'too many views warning', but despite reusing some view using the `include` tags the warning still remains.

> LayoutName.xml has more than 80 views, bad for performance

**CODE:** http://pastebin.com/6wUBd3Fb

The code from the link above is exactly how I want my layout to appear hence I must ask this: Do `include` tags help lower the view count or do `include` tags actually also count as a 'view'?

Comment: Goodness, that's a lot of views.

Comment: How about removing the linear layouts and leaving their children on the RelativeLayout and using "toLeftOf", "toRightOf" or "below" to align them.
Is this possible for you?

Comment: Please reengineer your UI. As of now, it's a **mess**. And it's using **layout nesting**, which is really a **worst practice**.

Comment: Study in depth how RelativeLayouts work. They are very helpful to dramatically reduce layout nesting. Also try to differently arrange your UI blocks. A ListView or an ExpandableListView is often helpful.

Comment: On a quick count I found 20 LinearLayouts on your code so I'm sure removing some of these will help

Comment: So, if they tell you to jump out of the window, you will? I mean... don't follow your boss, if it's unreasonable. Convince them that YOU are right.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein How am I supposed to use layout weights? It's better to use that rather than dp sizes which is why I use linear layouts in the first place.

Comment: Why is using layout weights mandatory?

Comment: Maybe GridViews can help.

Comment: But you know it can reduce your `layout` count (and nesting).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Interestingly Android Studio doesn't tell me how many views there actually are in the layout which is a huge disappointment. All I can refer to is the Structure pane which is very time consuming when counting.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein What about a Table Layout?

Comment: Also. But I'm concerned with the TableRows, which I consider a form of layout nesting.

Comment: You actually have a ton of includes (why?). Try removing them and put all in a layout. I'd try to visualize the structure on paper. Decide what is really needed and what isn't. What can be simplified. What can be changed. And try to optimize.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein They used to be 'views' but I changed them to 'includes' because I thought that would reduce the number of views. I visualised this a while ago and I don't know how to modify the code to simplify it and reduce the number of views. The appearance is perfect is just the view count that's the problem.

Comment: The View count includes the Layout count (also known as ViewGroups).

Comment: @FrankN.Stein OK well I changed them back to Views. The only thing I can think of is removing the linear layouts for the top and bottom rows but then I don't know how to get even spacing between the red windows. `layout_weight` was so easy for this back then.

Comment: Even spacing. As in a [GridView](http://developer.android.com/intl/ja/guide/topics/ui/layout/gridview.html). Obviously, you can have GridViews with a single row, if so you need. But it doesn't seem the case, here. As fa as I understood, you need a GridView to replace all the LinearLayouts - And (possibly) the RelativeLayout as well. Depending on what's in the included layouts (if you have the infamous combination ImageView + TextView), you can get rid of the ImageViews by using compound drawables

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I haven't used any image views at all. All the red windows were made from drawables. Which is better, a GridView or a TableView? Also would that reduce the number of views?

Comment: IMO, the GridViews are better. Since they don't need the TableRows (which introduce layout nesting). They will for sure introduce the Layout (= ViewGroup) count. So, yes, the overall View count will be reduced.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein What about using onDraw()?

Comment: Even better. If you only want to decorate your background, that would be the PERFECT solution.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein Not sure what you mean by that but it needs to look exactly like this image (see link below). Each red border is filled grey - I created a drawable for that, which can reused. IMHO due to it's complexity it would be a miracle and I'd be gobsmacked if you/anyone knew how to do this using onDraw(). I know a class needs to be created but I don't know what to do after that. 

http://picpaste.com/Screen_Shot_2015-08-13_at_15.07.00.png

Comment: Well. This, at first, suggests me that it could be split into `4 pages` (thus dividing the single page View count by 4). Then, do the red squares change their states (likely on click), or are they a ViewPager thingy?

Comment: @FrankN.Stein No! It is all one image created from multiple objects. It doesn't need any view pagers nor click events at all. All it needs is onDraw() in Java + custom java class define in XML

Comment: Then I really can't understand why you can't use an image. Or a 9 patch.

Comment: @FrankN.Stein I want to be able to edit the image later on hence I feel onDraw is best for this.

Comment: Well, it's the a 2 faces of a coin: on one hand, you have it **easy** (background image). On the other hand you can change the code behaviour and draw it parametrically (you might select a color in the preferences or decide to only show the upper or lowersquares, to say some) - at the price of some CPU work. In both cases, you will **decimate** the View count. And possibly **get rid** of the layout nesting.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

By loooking your xml layout, does appear that you are trying to display rows of data on the screen. You can use a ListAdapter instead and create the layout of the row within the Adapter.

You will have less code but the number of views will remain those only displayed (ignoring cliped views off the scroll)